# Session Expired when using Passportjs Facebook from Facebook App in IOS

Tags: passport.js, passport-facebook, passport-facebook-token

I tried using passportjs facebook on my website and tested on different browser but there’s a little bit problem when the link is from the facebook app itself specifically on IOS.

Package used: http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-facebook/

The scenario is:

- Share your login url to post in your facebook timeline
- Open facebook app on ipad
- Click the link that was posted on facebook timeline to open the login url and a popup browser from facebook app should appear.
- Click your facebook login using passportjs

Result:
Session Expired popup appear and you’ll be sign out and ask to login again but not from your url but from the app itself so I’m not getting the response login from it since it is not from passportjs login anymore. Any idea how to solve this or why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some trial & error reading I found out I just need to turn on the "Force Web OAuth Reauthentication" inside Facebook Developer dashboard and now it continue login from IOS Facebook app when the link is from their.

[image]